# How to remove coloured degradation from old photo in GIMP

Tags: color, gimp, restoration

I have a lot of old photos in my family history file. The one I'm looking at has obviously suffered from some kind of degradation of the silver/silver chemicals:

[image]

It has a sort of haze over parts of the surface, which is a sort of cyan colour (as opposed to the sepia coloured genuine image). I have scanned it in colour, and I want to try to remove the cyan(ish) haze without damaging the underlying image. Since they are a different colour, this (it seems to me) ought to be possible. How would I do this in GIMP?

Thanks - Rowan

Comment: You might be able to reduce the cyan noise, but what lies behind it? Nothing I am afraid. Pixels cannot hide other pixels behind them. I see no trace of the original image through the haze. It seems to be opaque. If the contours of the image was visible but tinted by the haze there might be a chance.

Comment: I think this photo is a loss. It's not correctable short of painting it entirely.

Comment: This actually looks like specular highlights introduced by scanning a matte (or "satin") textured photo print on a flatbed scanner. For posterity, better results may be gotten using a decent camera or DSLR on a tripod. This is a comment since it does not address the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the digitized source that I am going to tackle in the steps below using Gimp-

1. **Remove sepia and green stain by choosing *Colors > Desaturate***

   [image]
2. **Weaken the scratches**

   - Choose a sensible *Colors > Treshold* value to obtain an inverted "scratch" template.

     [image]
   - Copy this template onto the desaturated original from 1. in *"Overlay"*-Mode

     [image]
3. **Adjust the *Color Curve* to control lights and shadows**

   [image]
4. **Despeckle photo with the *Filters > Enhance > Despeckle* tool**

   [image]

The huge black scratches can best be removed manually. Still, mostly because of the quite bad degradation the photo suffered the results are far from optimal.

[image]

We can also see quite strong JPG-artifacts in this enhanced version. THis  may be much better when working on an uncompressed source scan.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the cyan haze is opaque. No software can see what's behind it.

Option 1:

- turn the haze to less optrusive by turning it's brightness region more flat with the curves tool
- Reduce flat haze by shifting the black level to higher with the curves tool
- recolor the image to monochrome.

The result:

[image]

This makes hazed areas nearly black, which probably isn't wanted

Option 2:

Goto a specialist who check, if the error is not in the photo emulsion, but in the upper surface. Then he maybe can remove the haze mechanically or chemically. I can see, that someone has wipd part of the haze off.

Of course he can have wiped off some chemical that has spoiled the photo elsewhere. In that case yoy are out of luck.

Option 3:

Try to find another image which contains some vanished details. They probably can be moved from a photo to another.